# CloudLinux server won't boot

Tags: linux, centos, raid, boot

I have a cPanel server, running Cloud Linux, it's a dedicated server that originally ran CentOS 6.4 and SoftRaid 1. I converted it to CloudLinux after a fresh re-install. I didn't have a need to restart it, until now. Everything was running smoothly, but when I rebooted the server it shut down, but it didn't come back up. The provider put it into Rescue Mode, since **I can't use KVM nor IPMI.** I ran a hardware test, and everything is alright. I tried re-installing GRUB, but it doesn't change anything. The server still won't boot. I'm really out of ideas at this point. The provider is an unmanaged one, I'm keeping the reinstall as the last resort.

I used this tutorial to re-install GRUB: http://www.adminlinux.org/2009/10/how-to-reinstall-grub-while-in-rescue.html

EDIT:

The provider told me this shows up on the screen while booting up:

```
*An error occurred during the file system check*
*Dropping you to a shell; the system will reboot*
```

I did some research and I need to run fsck.

When I try to run fsck /dev/sda1 I keep getting this:

```
root@rescue [/]# fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
fsck: fsck.linux_raid_member: not found
fsck: Error 2 while executing fsck.linux_raid_member for /dev/sda1
```

That's when the drive is mounted, then I tried unmounting it,

```
root@rescue [/]# fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
/dev/sda1 is in use.
Aborted
```

I am doing all this in rescue mode.

I have 2 drives 1TB each in Raid 1 here is fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md1        /       ext3    errors=remount-ro,usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0      0       1
/dev/md3        /home   ext3    usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0        1       2
/dev/sda2       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
/dev/sdb2       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs   defaults                0       0
tmpfs       /dev/shm tmpfs  noexec,nosuid   0   0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  defaults        0       0
/tmp_fs /tmp ext3 noexec,nosuid,loop,rw 1 1
```

UPDATE:

As Bittylicious suggested I executed the commands and here are the results:

```
root@rescue:~# mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
mdadm: /dev/sda1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 is busy - skipping
```

Then I assumed the raid was already assembled so I did:

```
root@rescue:~# fsck /dev/md1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/: recovering journal
Setting free inodes count to 9410644 (was 9410650)
Setting free blocks count to 35082532 (was 35082538)
/: clean, 190380/9601024 files, 3317196/38399728 blocks
```

UPDATE #2:

Here is the mount result:

```
root@rescue:~# mount
none on / type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
198.27.85.63:/home/pub/rescue.v7 on /nfs type nfs (ro,relatime,vers=3,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,namlen=255,hard,nolock,proto=udp,port=2049,timeo=11,retrans=3,sec=sys,local_lock=all,addr=198.27.85.63)
198.27.85.63:/home/pub/pro-power on /power type nfs (ro,nodev,relatime,vers=3,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,namlen=255,hard,nolock,proto=udp,port=2049,timeo=11,retrans=3,sec=sys,local_lock=all,addr=198.27.85.63)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=807512k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1615020k)
rpc_pipefs on /nfs/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
```

Here is the fsck /dev/md3 result:

```
root@rescue:~# fsck /dev/md3
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/home: clean, 370962/50429952 files, 5187714/201693680 blocks
```

mkswap on sda2:

```
root@rescue:~# mkswap /dev/sda2
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 16382972 KiB
no label, UUID=b375ef52-9434-4298-be4a-38db9da029af
```

mkswap on sdb2:

```
root@rescue:~# mkswap /dev/sdb2
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 16382972 KiB
no label, UUID=f9318100-c18d-4987-b4e8-6bc58b0c8299
```

UPDATE #3:

I'm assuming Bittylicious ment the /boot/grub/grub.conf, in that case:

```
default=0
timeout=5

        title CloudLinux Server (2.6.32-458.6.2.lve1.2.30.el6.x86_64)
        kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-458.6.2.lve1.2.30.el6.x86_64 root=/dev/md1 $
        root (hd0,0)
        initrd /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-458.6.2.lve1.2.30.el6.x86_64.img
        title linux centos6_64
        kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 root=/dev/md1  ro
        root (hd0,0)
        initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64.img
```

I've also tried rebuilding initramfs. I followed this tutorial:
http://advancelinux.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-rebuild-initrd-or-initramfs-in.html

Comment: Check if all the devices in /etc/fstab exist. Run fsck on them.

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many reasons why it couldn't boot. We could all list a number of reasons (and I will) but at the end of the day there must be some way you can get your provider to help out. Even if they just read what's on the console, it will provide massive clues as to how to fix it.

My suggestions for now are:

- You haven't set up an initramfs/initrd but yet you're specifying it
- You've specified one, but it doesn't contain the relevant drivers to mount your root filesystem
- You're using a hypervisor that can't load an initrd/ramfs/kernel image in the compressed format it's in

Most unmanaged providers do provide support, even it's payable. I suggest you fork out for it as you'll spend way too long trying to guess this without any kind of kernel access.

Update 1 - now that you've added information fsck, it's quite simple. You are trying to run fsck on a RAID member - this won't work. What you need to do is to assemble the RAID array first (and then possibly run fsck on that).

Why are you running fsck on /dev/sda1 anyway? What you probably need to do is something like:

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

(assuming that sda1 and sdb2 are your RAID members)

If that worked, then you can run fsck on /dev/md1. What you really need to figure out is why your OS didn't assemble the RAID array. My best guess is that it's degraded, and you need to add 'bootdegraded' to your kernel options.

Update 2 - Let's get more info:

1. When you reinstalled GRUB, do you know what the contents of your grub.cfg or boot.lst file were so we can figure out your boot options?
2. Have you tried rebuilding your initramfs (update-initramfs -k all -u just to start)

Comment: I have got them to provide me with the error that shows up on the console:

*An error occurred during the file system check*
*Dropping you to a shell; the system will reboot*

Comment: OK, that's a good start. I would get them to provide more information still (maybe even just ask them to take a photo)? This could be as simple as your /etc/fstab being wrong though, certain mountpoints not existing etc.

Honestly, as said before, just pay them a small amount to get your system booted. It'll be easier than going back and forth.

Comment: Believe me at this point I'd be glad to pay them to help me. But they keep shooting me down. Anyways, I have update the post.

Comment: 1. Get a new hosting provider - that's a poor show.
2. I have updated my answer with a likely solution.

Comment: I see, I did the commands, and I know it is poor, I'm looking for a replacement, but I can't leave this server just hanging. I have updated the post with the results from the commands performed.

Comment: OK great. We're getting there now. You have successfully run fsck on your root filesystem.

It might boot up now (can't be sure) but we're not sure exactly what filesystem check was failing upon bootup. Can you run 'mount' so we can see what's actually mounted? Run fsck on /dev/md3 and maybe even mkswap on /dev/sda2 and /dev/sdb2 to recreate your swap devices.

Comment: Updated the post (UPDATE #2).

Comment: OK. I'd risk another reboot. It's always possible that the /etc/inittab (possibly in your initramfs) is trying to mount something silly but give it a go. Ask your datacentre guys to take a photo of the screen if it doesn't boot again (as this might give more information).

Comment: I rebooted the server, and the datacenter says the only thing that shows up on the screen is:  "an error occurred during the files system check"

Comment: Gah, that's annoying. I wish we could figure out what filesystem wasn't mounting. The thing is, it starts getting difficult because /etc/fstab (the list of directories to mount) is in your initramfs and not that easy to modify.

I'll add a few more ideas in my answer.

Comment: Updated the post (UPDATE #3). I will reboot the server now, maybe the  initramfs fixed something.

Comment: Update, I didn't do anything. Still not booting.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stuck now. It looks like you're using /dev/md1 as the root which is fine as that appears to be assembled just as you'd expect.

Comment: I understand. I mounted /dev/md1 to /mnt, then did chroot /mnt and from there I went to /boot/grub/grub.conf. This is probably against the rules, but my email is filipovic103@gmail.com I can provide you with access so you can see for your self. (I am sorry if it's against the rules)